# R: Binding columns by key variable

Tags: r, left-join, inner-join, cbind

I want to combine two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, by different groups of a key variable in `x1`. It is basically some join operation, however, I do not want the rows to duplicate and do not care about the relationship among the added columns.

Assume:

`df1`:

```
x1 x2 
A  1
A  2
A  3
B  4
B  5
C  6
C  7
```

`df2`:

```
x1 x3 
A  a
A  b
A  c
A  d
A  e
A  f
B  g
C  h
```

The result should look like this.

`df1` + `df2`:

```
x1 x2 x3 
A  1  a
A  2  b
A  3  c
A  NA d
A  NA f
B  4  g
B  5  NA
C  6  h
C  7  NA
```

Does anyone have an idea? I would most appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The full_join in dplyr works well for this too. See below:

```
  #recreate your data
  library (data.table)
  library (dplyr)

  df1 <- data.table (x1 = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C"), x2 = seq (from = 1, to = 7))

  df2 <- data.table (x1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","C"), x3 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h" ))

  df1[, rowid := rowid(x1)]

  df2[, rowid := rowid(x1)]

  df3 <- full_join (df1, df2, by = c ("x1","rowid"))

  df3$rowid <- NULL

  setorder (df3, x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To replicate your resulting `data.frame` you can create row ids by `x1` and then merge on those row ids and `x1` (but I don't really know if that is what you are trying to accomplish)

```
library(data.table)

df1 = read.table(text = "x1 x2 
A  1
A  2
A  3
B  4
B  5
C  6
C  7", header = T)

df2 = read.table(text = "x1 x3 
A  a
A  b
A  c
A  d
A  e
A  f
B  g
C  h", header = T)

setDT(df1) 
setDT(df2)
df1[, rowid := seq(.N), by = x1] # create rowid
df2[, rowid := seq(.N), by = x1] # create rowid

merge(df1, df2, by = c("x1", "rowid"), all = T)[, rowid := NULL][]

    x1 x2 x3
 1:  A  1  a
 2:  A  2  b
 3:  A  3  c
 4:  A NA  d
 5:  A NA  e
 6:  A NA  f
 7:  B  4  g
 8:  B  5 NA
 9:  C  6  h
10:  C  7 NA
```

Comment: Fyi, there's a function for that: `df1[, rowid := rowid(x1)]`

Comment: Thanks so much, this is awsome!